Hangfire multiple servers not running concurrently
In a Saas app, we want order imports to run in serial for each tenant. But multiple order imports can run concurrently for different tenants (up to a point). Then also runs other types of jobs that again I'd like to run serially by tenant, but multiple tenants can run concurrently.
i.e.
OrderImportServer - max 20 workers total

Tenant1q_OI - runs serial
Tenant2q_OI - runs serial
Tenant3q_OI - runs serial

OrderReleaseServer - max 20 workers total

Tenant1q_OR - runs serial
Tenant2q_OR - runs serial
Tenant3q_OR - runs serial

How can you accomplish this in Hangfire?
We're using Asp.Net and Hangfire version 1.8.11 utilizing SQL Server for hangfire storage.
I was hoping I could set a WorkerCount by server to indicate the max number of concurrent jobs running and then have queues inside the server that run serially (i.e. max of 1 worker per queue), but I'm unclear it the latter is possible. i.e. if I set a server to use 4 workers, and only 1 queue has 10 enqueued jobs, I'm afraid the queue will then run jobs 1 - 4 in parallel, which I don't want.
Is there a way to accomplish this desired result? Perhaps using a Server per tenant that has 1 WorkerCount and then limit the max concurrent jobs via the [MaximumConcurrentExecution][1]?
OrderImportTenant1Server

OIT1Q

OrderImportTenant2Server

OIT2Q

OrderReleaseTenant1Server

ORT1Q

OrderReleaseTenant2Server

ORT2Q

This just seems like a lot of servers with 1 queue each...not sure that matters from a technical perspective, it just seems easier to think of a "Server" as a job type (Order Import vs Order Release) and then have queues by tenant within them.

I don't think that this is possible with hangfire at least not with Hangfire package. Not sure how may feature does the Hangfire.Pro and Hangfire.Ace. I know that in Hangfire.Ace you can chose max amount of jobs to run concurrently and that Pro has batching. But those are paid Hangfire packages.

@J.Memisevic I think the only part not in Hangfire is the MaxConcurrentConnections, which I linked to a third party solution. So I think this can be accomplished, utilizing that, but it's a lot of servers and a tad messy from an organizational standpoint.
